ubuntu 22 in Vmware , cyclictest has very bad results
i am having difficulty with ubuntu in a vmware environment , need some expert eyes on this and let me know what could be wrong or changes which need to be done in vmware or the guest OS . tested the same with low latency kernel also.
#/dev/cpu_dma_latency set to 0us WARN: reported clock resolution: 1 nsec WARN: measured clock resolution approximately: 25 nsec policy: fifo: loadavg: 0.57 0.21 0.13 1/535 923887
T: 0 (923834) P:99 I:1000 C: 16028 Min: 11 Act: 11 Avg: 235 Max: 2089577

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79313603/ubuntu-22-in-vmware-cyclictest-has-very-bad-results
